# Why [if ...] condition doesn't work in my html?

Tags: javascript, html

I open this html-file in **Google Chrome 70.0.3538.67** and **Internet Explorer 11.55.17763.0**:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script>
        console.log('Hello all!')
    </script>
    <!--[if gt IE 9]>
    <script>
        console.log('Hello from IE newer then 9!')
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the output for both browsers:

> Hello all!
>   Hello from IE newer then 9!

But I get only:

> Hello all!

Why does it happen?

Comment: As the syntax highlighting clearly shows, the comment doesn't end before the `<script>` tag but encloses it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Conditional comments were proprietary to Internet Explorer, and never supported in other browsers. Support was removed from IE in [version 10](https://www.sitepoint.com/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/).

This technique is obsolete and should no longer be depended on (unless you are explicitly targeting IE versions 5 through 9).